# Main.exe producing no output?

Tags: c, gcc, sdl-2

I am trying to learn **SDL2** using **c** and **gcc**, so I copied this from a website (probably from 2011).

##### Problem

My code doesn't produce any output as soon.
For instance, in the code (right below this paragraph) the two `printf()` never do a thing.

The `test()`, which is supposed to create an empty **SDL2** window is, too, not working.

##### Code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
    #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
    #endif
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>   

 
void test(){
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 4);
        
        SDL_Window* window = NULL;
        
    
        if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
        {
            printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        }
        else
        {
            window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Tutorial", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
            if( window == NULL )
           {
                printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            }
           
    }}
    
    int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
        printf("Test", "\n"); //Debug
        test();
        printf("Done", "\n"); //Debug
    }
```

##### Console Command

```
gcc -std=c11 main.c -IC:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\sdl2\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-mingw\SDL2-2.0.18\i686-w64-mingw32\include -LC:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\sdl2\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-mingw\SDL2-2.0.18\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
a.exe
```

##### What I tried

I completely removed any reference to `test()`, which fixed the problem(I saw my output again).
But its still a problem; I need my `test()`

##### Conclusion

Although it may be obvious now, I would like it to work, and so I wrote this stack overflow question hoping that someone explains me what have I done wrong.

Comment: Maybe your program silently crashes? Launch it by double-clicking in the explorer, sometimes it gives better error messages. If it doesn't help, use your debugger.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  it does say that my app didnt start properly, but it dont understand the error code (`0x0..07b`)

Comment: Does your debugger show a stack trace? A random guess, try adding `return 0;` at the end of `main`.

Comment: Nope, nothing shows.

Comment: Come on. Explain what exactly did you do with the debugger, and what exactly it shows.

Comment: A bit far-fetched, but try an explicit `fflush(stdout);` after each printf.

Comment: `PS C:\Users\Utilisateur\pistachotron-1> ./run-windows

C:\Users\Utilisateur\pistachotron-1>gcc -std=c11 main.c -IC:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\sdl2\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-mingw\SDL2-2.0.18\i686-w64-mingw32\include -LC:\Users\Utilisateur\Desktop\sdl2\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-mingw\SDL2-2.0.18\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

C:\Users\Utilisateur\pistachotron-1>a.exe`
(On windows powershell) This is my whole process

Comment: Does this mean you didn't try a debugger yet?

Comment: `fflush does nothing`

Comment: A debugger? I never heard about that (im new to c).

Comment: It's good that you figured out that calling `test()` makes the program not work, and not calling it lets the program run.  Now, narrow down your problem further. 
 Take out lines from test(), one-by-one, from the bottom, and try running the program again. See if you get output. Do this until you find the one line that causes the program to start working.

Comment: You'll need to learn to use it sooner or later, might as well start now. It will show you where exactly the program crashes.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. I will also learn to use debuggers.

Comment: `printf("Test", "\n");` doesn't do what you probably think it does. Try `printf("Test\n");` instead.  Do you see the *first* output now?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I saw that too but then `fflush(stdout)` ought to have fixed it.

Comment: Once you have sorted `printf` out, consider this. Your program opens a window, and then... what should happen? Should the program stop and wait you...  do what exactly? Should the program continue running, print "Done", exit, and leave the window open? What are the other options?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I did, it doesnt change anything. And my point **is** to create a window. Its just for learning.

Comment: For how long do you plan to observe the window?

Comment: Please update your [mre] to contain the fixed  `printf()`s. Then describe what you observe. Without `test()` you get what output? With `test()` you observe what?

Comment: @LeonLavoie what's the output of `file a.exe`?

Comment: @keltar On Windows, the `file` command does not exist

Comment: @astroide meh, i thought it is part of mingw suite, but apparently it is in git for windows instead

Comment: @LeonLavoie if `file` is not available to you then, eh, blindly add `-mconsole` to your build flags. It should be the default though. Remove your `SDL_MAIN_HANDLED` as you link with `SDL2main` anyway.

Comment: Without ` test()` the two ` printf()`s shows up. After further debugging , any SDL2 function "mute" the program.